# How to call the stored procedure with parameters in python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a stored procedure defined **escalate** which taking a string parameter **clientid**.

I'm using sqlalchemy in python and using ORM. I have db.session created.

I'm not sure how i could call stored procedure with this session.

Anyone could point me the solution?

I have tried following; but getting an error:

> TypeError: get_bind() got an unexpected keyword argument 'param'

Code:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_, func,text

db.session.execute(text("CALL escalate(:param)"), param=clientid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html?highlight=session#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute) `session.execute` needs a dict over kwargs, [unlike the connection object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html?highlight=connection#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute) which should have worked as you wrote it.

```py
db.session.execute(
    "CALL escalate(:param)",
    {'param': clientid}
)
```

Comment: do you know why i face this error?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58987744/why-the-stored-procedure-called-from-sqlalchemy-is-not-working-but-calling-from They way i call storedprocedure is right or wrong?