# why the stored procedure called from sqlalchemy is not working but calling from workbench is working?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a stored procedure.

calling it via MySQL workbench as follows working;

```
CALL `lobdcapi`.`escalatelobalarm`('A0001');
```

But not from the python program. (means it is not throwing any exception, process finish execution silently) if I make any error in column names, then at python I get an error. So it calls my stored procedure but not working as expected. (it is an update query .it needs SAFE update )

Why through the python sqlalchemy this update didn't update any records?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`lob`@`%` PROCEDURE `escalatelobalarm`(IN client_id varchar(50))
BEGIN

 SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;                                   
update lobdcapi.alarms
    set lobalarmescalated=1
where id in (

    SELECT al.id 
    from (select id,alarmoccurredhistoryid from lobdcapi.alarms where lobalarmpriorityid=1 and lobalarmescalated=0 and clientid=client_id 
            and alarmstatenumber='02' ) as al
    inner join lobdcapi.`alarmhistory` as hi on hi.id=al.alarmoccurredhistoryid
            and hi.datetimestamp<=  current_timestamp() )

);

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;

END
```

I call it like;

```
from sqlalchemy import and_, func,text


db.session.execute(text("CALL escalatelobalarm(:param)"), {'param': clientid})
```

I suspect the param I pass via code didn't get bind properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [stored procedures with sqlAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563738/stored-procedures-with-sqlalchemy)

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari i got answer from Krik. It is simple, I haven't used session.commit that was the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't called stored procs from SQLAlchemy, but it seems possible that this could be within a transaction because you're using the session. Perhaps calling `db.session.commit()` at the end would help?

If that fails, SQLAlchemy calls out [calling stored procs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#calling-stored-procedures) here. Perhaps try their method of using `callproc`. Adapting to your use-case, something like:

```py
connection = db.session.connection()
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc("escalatelobalarm", [clientid])
    results = list(cursor.fetchall())
    cursor.close()
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,db.session.commit() solved the problem